# Pokemon GO: Empty Map

Tags: pokemon-go

When I'm in a rural area, using android 5.1.1, there are no problems with the map.

However, when I'm in an urban area, most of the time, I experience a blank map, especially in crowded places like malls.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to wifi networks automatically out in public areas? They could be IP banned or you may not have reconnected properly when changing networks.

Comment: Or it's unable to download the maps from Google.